# Rendering dynamic select options Vue/Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I wrote the following code to dynamically create a v-model for each select box I have on my page.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <tbody v-for="match in matchData.results" :key="match.id">
            <tr class="border-b">
                <td class="py-2 px-6 max-w-xs">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <input v-model="queries[match.id]" @input="debounceSearchMatch(match.id)" type="text" class="block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-1 px-4 text-sm shadow-sm outline-none" placeholder="Search" />
                        <div class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 z-20 flex items-center pr-2">
                            <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" class="fa-sm text-navy-100" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="relative w-11/12">
                        <select v-model="selectInputs[match.id]" class="block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-1 pl-6 pr-11 text-sm shadow-sm outline-none text-gray-500">
                            <option :value="result.id" v-for="result in results[match.id]" :key="result.id">{{result.home.name}} - {{ result.away.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

let timeoutId: null | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = null
let results : any[] = []; 

export default Vue.extend({
    props: ["data"],
    data() {
        return {
            matchData: this.$props.data,
            debounceTimeout: timeoutId,
            selectInputs: [],
            results: results,
            queries: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        debounceSearchMatch: function (matchId: number) {
            if (this.debounceTimeout)
                clearTimeout(this.debounceTimeout);
            this.debounceTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.searchMatch(matchId);
            }, 500);
        },
        searchMatch: async function (matchId: number) {
            this.results[matchId] = await this.$axios.get(`/matches?query=${this.queries[matchId]}`).then((response) => {
                return response.data.results
            })
        }
    },
})
</script>
```

Currently the issue I'm facing is that when I search for "test" in one of the select boxes the options of the select box aren't updated. Then when I search using the same select box for another term I'm displayed the results of my previous query.

If I don't use `results[match.id]` and instead write my results directly to `results` in the fetch method then the issue is gone. However this is not a solution because I have to store the results per select box.

Comment: Hi, 168 lines of code is pretty broad. Mind narrowing those down a bit for a scoped issue to solve?

Comment: @kissu Hi, narrowed it down till about 50 lines.